# Flask is not reading CSS file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I've scoured for a typo and tried several fixes I've found across this site and my styles still aren't being applied. 
The directory structure is as follows:

```
ResumeSite
----/static
--------/img
------------img1.jpg
------------img2.jpg
--------style.css
----/templates
--------index.html
app.py
```

The CSS file is as follows:

```
/* CSS Variables */

:root {
    --primary: #ddd;
    --dark: #333;
    --light: #fff;
    --shadow: 0 1px 5x rgba(104, 104, 104, 0.8);
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: var(--dark);
}

body {
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 30px 50px;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

.btn {
    background-color: var(--dark);
    color: var(--light);
    padding: 0.6rem 1.3rem;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.showcase h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

In the index.html file, I have the stylesheet linked properly with Jinja syntax:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
```

I'm not sure at this point what the issue is, when I run the server, I get a command line message that states:

```
GET HTTP:1 200 -
```

I believe the 200 means success however no styles are being applied no matter what I've tried so far.

Comment: Are you working with a Windows system? If so you might have saved styles.css as styles.css.css without realizing.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows and VSCode and I created the file directly from the editor directory and it is named properly. The command line doesn't state any errors when I run the server, if the file was named incorrectly it would output a 404 error and say something like style.css.css not found

Comment: create a directory structure as "static/css/style.css". because flask looks for css files inside from "static/css". Hope it works

Comment: are you running the debug mode ? you should see a line like `"GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -` in the console

Comment: @PRMoureu yes I'm in debug mode and that is the line I get in the terminal when the server is run or refreshed

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from the code you posted, but if you are using Boostrap, make sure your reference to `style.css` file is made AFTER the reference to `bootstrap.css`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='bootstrap.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='style.css') }}">
```

Otherwise your changes will be overridden with the default bootstrap styles

Comment: I will have to try this when I'm able to later, I never thought about this because I am using Font Awesome CDN for icons throughout the html. That would explain why there is no errors because the reference to my styles is simply being overridden. I don't know off the top of my head how I have the references ordered because I don't currently have the code in front of me but I will edit this later after I try this fix.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply that the CSS file resided in the top level of the static directory and not within a sub-folder named 'css'. Thank you @Manish Mahendru for mentioning this, I will have to remind myself in the future the proper structure for a flask application.